# Different number of posts in each category

Tags: posts, categories, cms, codex, limit

I have categories driven site. I have different template for each category. I would like to set different number of posts – **different for each category**. Plus I would like to add proper previous and next links in each category.

for example in this `category-1.php` I want 4 posts per page:

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=4'); ?>
<a href="<?=next_posts()?>"> PREVIOUS </a>
<a href="<?=previous_posts()?>"> NEXT </a>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
...
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

but in this example `next_posts()` and `previous_posts()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [@StephenHarris pointed out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4093036#4093036) there's also the [`pre_get_posts` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

```
function hwl_home_pagesize( $query ) 
{
    if ( is_category( 9 ) ) 
    {
        // If you want "posts per page"
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 1;
        return;
    }
    if ( is_category( 'movie' ) )
    {
        // If you want "showposts"
        $query->query_vars['showposts'] = 50;
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hwl_home_pagesize', 1 );
```

<sup>Example altered from Codex example.</sup>

Comment: Don't mark this one as solution. @StephenHarris and me just posted at the same sec. Go down to his one and mark this one. Thanks.

Comment: same as in @StephenHarris solution

Comment: But it was a) his solution and b) we posted at the same time. So please unmark this (upvoting is appreciated) and mark his as the solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook (conditionals are available):

```
function wpse47875_change_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    //Only alter main query. This only works for 3.3+
    if( ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if ( is_category('9') ){
        //Display 4 posts for category 1
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 4);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse47875_change_posts_per_page', 1);
```

You probably only want to change the 'main query', so the first check is important. If you are using WP < 3.3 then you can check instead:

```
 if( $wp_the_query === $query ){
    //$query is the main query
 }else{
    //$query is *not* the main query
 }
```

Comment: Excellent resource for understanding queries: http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-

Comment: It sets number of post correctly, but still on last post `next_posts()` prints **./category/project-name/page/5/** while **5** doesn't exist (404).

Comment: Something else must be interfering. This solution will work. It alters the post per page and Wordpress handles the rest including pagination. Next_posts is depreciated BTW

Answer (score 1):

### Parse Request Action

Not shure if this will work - it may be that the conditionals are not working at this point...

```
// inside functions.php
function wpse47861_intercept_main_query( $wp )
{
    // default
    $nr_posts = 10; 

    if ( is_category( 'CAT NAME' ) )
        $nr_posts = 4;

    if ( is_category( array( 9 /*Ex. Cat-ID*/, 'CAT NAME A', 'CAT NAME B' ) ) )
        $nr_posts = 6;

    // Modify the main query object
    $wp->query_vars['showposts'] = $nr_posts;

    return $wp;
}
add_filter( 'parse_request', 'wpse47861_intercept_main_query' );
```

### Posts Limit filter

This would be the other chance, as maybe conditionals are already available there.

```
function wpse47861_intercept_query_limit( $limit )
{
    // default
    $nr_posts = 10; 

    if ( is_category( 'CAT NAME' ) )
        $nr_posts = 4;

    if ( is_category( array( 9 /*Ex. Cat-ID*/, 'CAT NAME A', 'CAT NAME B' ) ) )
        $nr_posts = 6;

    return "LIMIT 0, {$nr_posts}";
}
add_filter( 'posts_limit', 'wpse47861_intercept_query_limit', 9999 );
```

*Note: Both functions are not tested. Plus: Use one **or** the other. Both should be placed in your functions.php file.*

Comment: I think conditionals doesn't work with 'request' filter, so can work with 'parse_request' action either.

Comment: @Mamaduka The order I thought about them was the other way around :) Maybe I should've split them up in different answers.

Answer (score 0):

With query_posts, pagination won't work correctly, unless you use query_posts() in a page template and you set the 'paged' query var appropriately: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts

But it may be easier to use a plugin called Custom Post Limits and leave your category page loops the same. You can set different first page and paged limits for each category. See [WordPress › Custom Post Limits « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-limits/)

Answer (score 0):

I have flexible way where is possible to set any per_page value for each/any woprdpress site page:

- open functions.php of the current wp theme
- use smth like next:

*

```
add_filter('pre_option_posts_per_page', function($num)
{
    if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] == '/category/faq/')
    {
    return 999;
    }

    return $num;
});
```

- use for example http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php for $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] with any patterns you want on the site to reach the goal!